# Check if exist data in table angular

Tags: angular

I have this function :

```
  onSubmit() {
     this.http.getDataFromServer('api/all').subscribe(resp => {
       console.log(resp.data)
    })

    this.http.postDataToServer('api/in', this.companyForm.value).subscribe(() => {
      //show that organization is added in dialog
      this.dialog.open(DisplayPopupComponent, {
        data: {
          title: "Organization Updated Successfully!"
        }
      });
    })
  }
```

We have data in `resp.data`, i want use this data out of this query to check if equal NULL or not to implement second query.

Graph :

resp.data -----> exist data? then apply second query (api/in).

```
      -----> NULL data do nothing.
```

Comment: You could call your second subscription in your subscription of the first. Or use [RXJS operators](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators) like `pipe` and `map` to achieve this result

Comment: How i do this in my example? @DTul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `switchMap`.

Here is an example:

```js
  onSubmit() {
    this.http.getDataFromServer('api/all').pipe(
      switchMap(resp => {
        if (resp.data) {
          return this.http.postDataToServer('api/in', this.companyForm.value);
        }
      })
    ).subscribe(() => {
      //show that organization is added in dialog
      this.dialog.open(DisplayPopupComponent, {
        data: {
          title: "Organization Updated Successfully!"
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Another question if i want get "id" from resp.data, note resp.data return json include "id", to use in another method in same component.ts, how to do this ? @oz1985oz

Comment: You can use `tap` method. For example you can add row before `switchMap`: `tap(resp => this.id = resp.data.id),`

Answer (score -1):

Try doing like this:

```
   onSubmit() {
         this.http.getDataFromServer('api/all').subscribe(resp => {
           console.log(resp.data)
           this.someVariablename = resp.data
        });

        if(this.someVariablename == null) {
         //do nothing
        }else{
          //do something
        this.http.postDataToServer('api/in', this.companyForm.value).subscribe(() => {
          //show that organization is added in dialog
          this.dialog.open(DisplayPopupComponent, {
            data: {
              title: "Organization Updated Successfully!"
            }
          });
        })
      }
}
```

Comment: Not work undefined this.someVariablename. @Kishan

Answer (score -1):

You can make a function for postDataToServer and call it if resp.data is available.

e.g.

```
 onSubmit() {
         this.http.getDataFromServer('api/all').subscribe(resp => {
           if(resp.data){
            this.postDataToServer();
    }
        })
    
    
       postDataToServer(){
    this.http.postDataToServer('api/in', this.companyForm.value).subscribe(() => {
          //show that organization is added in dialog
          this.dialog.open(DisplayPopupComponent, {
            data: {
              title: "Organization Updated Successfully!"
            }
          });
        })
    
    }
```